# Need major help solving an NP/ NP-Hard question

Tags: np, np-hard

So I am stuck on this problem and can not solve it for the life of me.  It is due tomorrow night, so if anyone could help me out by telling me the solution and how you got there, I would really appreciate it!

Input: a directed grid graph G, a set of target points S, and an integer k
Output: true if there is a path through G that visits all points in S using at most k left turns
A grid graph is a graph where the vertices are at integer coordinates from 0,0 to n,n. (So 0,0,  0,1,  0,2,  ...0,n,  1,0,  etc.) Also, all edges are between vertices at distance 1. (So 00->01, 00->10, but not 00 to any other vertex. Also some edges could be missing.)
Either give a polynomial time algorithm to solve this problem, or prove this problem is NP-hard.

Comment: Not really a programming problem since there’s nothing you’ve tried to program? Please take the [tour]

Comment: P, NP, and NP-hard are what is used to see if something can run in polynomial time.  So this is not specifically a programming question, but is used to see if a problem can even be solved fast enough on a program in which you are writing.  You want your stuff to be fast right?  Well this kind of problem is what you face when looking at polynomial time, which is important.  So if someone knows how to do this correctly it would help me out majorly.